# only first page of pdf is saved of a multiple page pdf in android

Tags: android, pdf

I have an android app where it is downloading a multiple page pdf which is getting opened perfectly in browser but when I am trying to download it on device it is getting downloaded but only first page is saved and not others.pls help
my code for downloading app -

edited code--

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(<url>);
BasicNameValuePair p1BasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("val1", <parameter to pass>);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairList.add(p1BasicNameValuePair);

try {
       UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new     UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);
       httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
       inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
       InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
       String bufferedStrChunk = null;
       File folder = new     File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
               File.separator + "<dir name>");
       boolean success = true;
       if (!folder.exists()) {
           success = folder.mkdirs();
      }
       if (success) {
       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
       fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(folder + "/" + "<filename>"+".pdf");
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
       int read;
       while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
       }
       fileOutputStream.flush();
       } else {
           // Do something else on failure
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:Unable to create directory",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
       }
       
       
   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       try {
           inputStream.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }

      }
```

Comment: `success = folder.mkdirs();` Take the consequences when no success. You continue as if nothing has has happened.`if ( !mkdirs() return;` You better care for a directory before you even try to start a download.

Comment: yes that I have in my mind but right now the issue of pdf ..at that moment I am only creating dir if it does not exist ..the other part will taken care of later..

Comment: Ok. Then i help you later when done with that ;-).

Comment: @blackapps I have modified the code according to you and still no success

Comment: I cannot see that you modified the code... And of course it will not solve your problem.. We are not that far yet... We read code top down and everything should be ok. At first error/flaw we stop .

Comment: check now I have edited code

Comment: `fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(folder + "/" + "<filename>"+".pdf");
` Still terrible.     `File file = new File (folder,  "<filename>"+".pdf");  fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);`

Comment: Can you suggest alternative for that...my main issue is of pdf

Comment: I already suggested an alternative.